# C++ type of elements point and more

Tags: c++, image-processing

In C++ we do

```
vector<Point> A;
```

then we have a vector full of `Point` named `A`.

Where do I find out the `Point` structure?

Meanwhile I checked `Point` here is called the *type* of the elements, any other type other than `Point`? Definitely not those simple ones like `int`, `short`, ...etc.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Standards C++ does not have any `Point` type. It must be something you included, or have to implement yourself.

Comment: What graphics libraries or framework are you using?

Comment: oh, i see, then it must be cv::Point.@ThomasMatthews